# pop up image from data-target on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link and next to it an icon:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="/link/to/image.jpg"><span id="icon"></span></a>
```

Can you show me a small js /jQuery/ code that shows a popup on mouse hover with the image from data-target at the bottom right position?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually to show this, you don't need jQuery at all, since you can do it just with css as here: http://jsfiddle.net/wwp66o9s/1/

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      This is some link
       <img src=http://lorempixel.com/400/200/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      This is some link
       <img src=http://lorempixel.com/400/200/>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      This is some link
       <img src=http://lorempixel.com/400/200/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>


li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
li a > img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 150px;
}
li a:hover > img {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here link is the class name on which it is hover

```
$(".link").mouseover(funtion(){
    var imagepath = $(this).attr("data-target")
    $( "this").tooltip({ content: "<img src='"+imagepath+"'/>" });  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/354/

I am using Bootstrap **List group** element and some custom **JQuery**. Also you can easily customize `window` class to match your needs.

```js
$('.list-group a').hover(function() {
  var image = $(this).data('target');
  $(this).append('<div class="window"><img src="'+image+'" alt=""></div>')
},function() {
  $(this).find('.window').remove();
});

var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = (e.pageX + 20) + 'px'; 
   mouseY = (e.pageY + 20) + 'px';
   $(this).find('.window').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX});
});
```

```css
.window {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.window img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a data-target="http://placehold.it/50x50/533A71/ffffff" href="#" class="list-group-item active">
          Cras justo odio
        </a>
        <a data-target="http://placehold.it/50x50/6184DB/ffffff" href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
        <a data-target="http://placehold.it/50x50/50C5B7/ffffff" href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
        <a data-target="http://placehold.it/50x50/9CEC5B/ffffff" href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
        <a data-target="http://placehold.it/50x50/F0F465/ffffff" href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I see some awesome examples, heres mine to throw into the mix.

**Note:** Using bootstrap for css.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2zLo9ty/18/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="list-group">
      <a data-target="link" href="#" class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</a>
      <a data-target="link" href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
      <a data-target="link" href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- should be build in js - placeholder -->
<div id="hover-container"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
(function($) {
    var placeholder = $("#hover-container");

    function mouseIn(event){
            var picture = '<img src="'+$(this).data("target")+'" alt="">';
        $(placeholder).html(picture);
    }

    function mouseOut(event) {
        $(placeholder).css({
            left: -1000,
            top: -1000
        });
        $(placeholder).html("");
    }

    $("*[data-target]").hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);

    $("*[data-target]").mousemove(function(){
                $(placeholder).css({
            left: event.pageX + 15,
            top: event.pageY + 15
        });       
    });

}) ($);
```

I wouldn't suggest building this yourself. As a tool for learning jQuery or sharpening your skills this is an excellent exercise, but ultimately its reinventing the wheel.

Heres an awesome library I have personally used. 
[qtip2](http://qtip2.com/)